# Можно не ставить тире между подлежащим и сказуемым?

Tags: тире

Текст:

*Она с радостью осталась бы здесь подольше. **Дядин зоомагазин чудесное место — в прямом смысле слова*** (Х. Вебб, 2019).

По правилам Розенталя тире должно ставится. Или это исключение?

Comment: У Розенталя там есть примечание, что тире обычно не ставится в простых по составу предложениях разговорного стиля.

Comment: А почему это разговорный стиль?  Детская художественная повесть,  вид текста —  описание. И не такое уж простое предложение. При отсутствии присоединительной конструкции там стояло бы тире: Дядин зоомагазин  —  чудесное место!

Comment: По моим ощущениям, это тире нужнее имеющегося, которое можно запятой или даже точкой (если нужна многозначительная пауза) заменить.

Comment: Alex_ander, согласитесь, странно  было бы что-то менять в предложении только на основании того, что  такая конструкция на упоминается в правилах.  Но она же существует в речи, ее использует автор. С таким походом мы  будем обеднять наш язык..

Comment: Это присоединительный член. Тире обосновано.

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю свой вариант объяснения, но при этом буду очень благодарна, если в своих ответах вы расскажете о том, встречались ли вам в литературе подобные предложения  и как они были оформлены.

**Условие задачи**

Дано предложение, в котором по правилам должно ставиться тире между подлежащим и сказуемым. Далее это предложение дополнено присоединительным оборотом, перед которым также должно ставиться тире по правилам.

(1) Дядин зоомагазин — чудесное место.

Она с радостью осталась бы здесь подольше. (2) Дядин зоомагазин чудесное место — в прямом смысле слова .

**Вопрос:**  Как оформить предложение? Можно ли оставить два тире или одно из них следует убрать?  Правильно ли поступил автор, убрав первое тире?

**Решение задачи**

1) Посмотрим, когда у Розенталя не ставится тире в подобных случаях. Это **два варианта:**

В специальной литературе при характеристике предмета тире в этом случае часто не ставится: Грузоподъёмность крана 2,5 тонны,

В простых по составу предложениях разговорного стиля: Моя мать инженер;  Мой брат школьник;

Можно, подумать, что **исключения** сделаны для двух тем по **семантическим** признакам. Но это не совсем так, варианты сходны и **по интонации тоже.** Паузы нет, а ударение падает на вторую часть предложения и не падает на первую.

Тогда мы предполагаем, что **при наличии этих признаков** не ставится тире и в других случаях.

2) И это как раз наше предложение, где добавление присоединительного оборота изменяет интонационную картину.

*Она с радостью осталась бы здесь подольше. **Дядин зоомагазин чудЕсное место — в прямом смысле слОва.***

Здесь две фразы, разделенные паузой. Главное — не делать ударение на слове ***зоомагазин***, первую часть произносить в одну фразу, без паузы, а  слово ***чудесное*** дополнительно выделить силовым ударением. Тогда предложение будет вполне читаемым, а интонация – выразительной.

**Примечание.** Можно предположить, что такое решение подходит для **не очень распространенных предложений,** когда прочтение первой части в одну фразу возможно.

[А это книга, стр.9, самое начало.](https://static.my-shop.ru/product/pdf/339/3380765.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Не захотел автор делать паузу и ударение - видимо, из-за того, что про этот магазин говорилось ранее. А соблюдать формализм, способствующий другой интонации, тоже не захотел. Но раз такое оформление не по правилам, то это авторская пунктуация.

Стоить заметить, что отсутствию паузы и тире способствует наличие лишь одного слова по одну сторону тире. Первый пункт исключений Розенталя тому в пример. А здесь по два слова.

Comment: А что же Розенталь не разобрал тот случай, где по два слова от тире. И где по три слова - тоже не разобрал.  Может быть, просто нельзя объять необъятное и всё разобрать? Наверное, нельзя жить только по Розенталю, и некоторые задачи нужно  самим научиться решать. Итак, это нерешенная задача. Неважно, что там про магазин говорилось раньше. В общем виде это выглядит так. После обычного предложения, в котором  ставится тие между подлежащим и сказуемым, следует присоединительный оборот, тоже обособленный тире. Может рассказать про интонацию и знаки препинания?

Comment: Розенталь разбирал не всё, что может существовать, а то, что существует в литературе. Он говорил, что, как писать правильно, ему подсказывает Пушкин. То есть он не руководствовался своим мнением. Причём это грамматический принцип - чётко отделить подлежащее и сказуемое. Перед оборотом действительно хочется поставить тире, так как слово ЭТО очень подставляется. В правилах не рассмотрено жертвование одним тире, а при двух получается какая-то вставка.

Comment: Меня огорчает не то, что вы не можете решить задачу, а скорее то, что вы не понимаете даже поставленные условия, а это самое важное в творческом мышлении.

Comment: Задача уже решена: первое тире убрано. Решать, переделывая предложение, что ли?

Comment: Объясните условия в вопросе, чтобы другим стало понятнее.

Comment: Другие у меня не спрашивают, а вам я уже объяснила. Вы можете сами придумать любое предложение по этой модели и предложить и обосновать общее решение

Comment: У меня возникали подобные проблемы. Тогда просто оставлял то тире, которое мне дороже. Но при этом лучше стараться не нарушать правила, чтобы никто не смог придраться.

Comment: Вы не понимаете, что такое правило. Правило - это задача, которую вам решил Розенталь для определенных УСЛОВИЙ.   Если условия изменить, то решение будет другое.

Comment: Хорошо, пусть будет так. Будем считать, что это ваш уровень понимания проблемы.

Comment: Решение такое: *Дядин зоомагазин — в прямом смысле слова чудесное место.* или *Дядин зоомагазин — чудесное место в прямом смысле слова.*

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что тире в первой части предложения необходимо. Попытка произнести "дядин зоомагазин чудесное место..." без паузы вынудила бы меня оформить это на письме следующим образом: "дядин зоомагазин "Чудесное место"...". Более того, я не считаю, что **в прямом смысле слова** необходимо выделять паузой в речи или знаками препинания на письме. Поэтому, вероятнее всего, тире ошибочно было поставлено не на то место. То есть я предполагаю здесь скорее опечатку при наборе, чем ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, но не согласна, увы!  Если вам не нравится мой интонационный анализ (этот метод мало кому нравится), то есть еще одно препятствие: нельзя ставить два РАЗНЫХ тире в одном предложении, иначе будет похоже на вставку. А присоединительная конструкция здесь нужна, так как это выделенная дополнительная информация, к тому же очень важная. Дело в том, что магазин был действительно  чудесным, так как в нем продавались волшебные животные. Об этом рассказывается дальше.

Comment: Мне нравится интонационный анализ (мы уже обсуждали это ранее) и именно из него я исхожу. Если второе тире настолько необходимо, тогда следовало бы (я считаю) как-то перестроить фразу — в русском языке такое случается. И я не вижу ничего страшного в том, что мы не согласны друг с другом :)

Comment: Меня в общем-то интересовало не конкретно это предложения, а сама модель, то есть встреча в одном предложении двух обязательных тире. А интонационный анализ - вещь новая, мало изученная. Я не вижу в здешних ответах цельности в применении этого метода анализа. Нет общей теоретической базы, поэтому люди путаются, бывают непоследовательными. Я применяю метод интонационных моделей, то есть  предложение строю из фонетических фраз, разделенных паузами.  Как это делают другие - я вообще не представляю, а они не понимают меня. Поэтому иногда сериал "один против всех" становится утомительным.